# Minimum of the absolute value of two unitary matrices elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Given two unitary matrices $A \in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}=\{a_{ij}\}_{i,j \in {1..n}}$  and $B \in\mathcal{M}_{p\times p}=\{b_{ij}\}_{i,j \in {1..p}}$ where n>p.

Can I say that $\min(|\{a_{ij}\}_{i,j \in {1..n}}|)\leq \min(|\{b_{ij}\}_{i,j \in {1..p}}|)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter-example using real matrices : Let $A=Id\in \mathcal{M}_{3\times3}$. Then $A$ is trivially unitary. Now let $$B=\begin{pmatrix}
cos(\theta) && -sin(\theta)\\
sin(\theta) && cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$

Be the rotation matrix (thus orthogonal, which is a special case of unitary) of angle $\theta$ in the plane. For $\theta\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, both $|cos(\theta)|$ and $|sin(\theta)|$ are smaller than one, so your inequality wont hold.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah I see.